# Javascript Array Scope - newbie here

Tags: javascript, arrays, gdata-api

So, I am learning Javascript while playing white Google Calendar APIs and I just can't figure how this piece of code is working this way:

```
var entriesResult = [];
var data = new Date(2010,3,22,17,0,0);
var callback = function(result) {       
    var entries = result.feed.getEntries();    
    if (entries.length != 0) {
        entriesResult = eventsManager(entries, 0, data);
        window.alert("inner entriesResult " + entriesResult.length);
    }
}
this.service.getEventsFeed(this.query, callback, handleGDError);
window.alert("outer entriesResult " + entriesResult.length);
```

eventsManager() is a function that returns an array of Objects.

getEventsFeed() it's an API function: it queries the service and pass a "feed root" (a feed with selected items) to the callback function.

Why the first alert (inner..) outputs a valid entriesResult.length while the second one (outer..) always outputs a 0?

I tought javascript arrays are always passed by reference, what's wrong whit my code?
Thank you :)

Comment: There's your problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getEventsFeed` function makes an asynchronous AJAX call and calls `callback` when the server replies.  In other words, the callback function is run some time after the rest of the code.

Therefore, the outer `alert` is executed before the callback, when the array is still empty.

### EDIT

To return a value from an AJAX call, you need to accept a callback as a parameter, then call the callback once you have a value to return.

For example:

```
function myFunction(someParam, callback) {
    //Do things...
    var eventsFeedCallback = function() { 
        //Do more things, and figure out what to return
        callback(someValue);  //Call the user's original callback to give back a value
    };
    this.service.getEventsFeed(this.query, eventsFeedCallback , handleGDError);  
    //Do more things...
}
```

You would call this function the same way you call `getEventsFeed`.
For example:

```
myFunction("Parameter!", function(value) {
    //This is the callback, and will be called when the AJAX call finishes
    //Do things with value
});
```

Comment: I see.
How can i resolve?
Because i need to return entriesResult.

Comment: You need to make your function take a callback instead of returning a value, just like `getEventsFeed`.  This is a fundamental limitation of AJAX.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I am really a newbie with js/ajax

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
 window.alert("outer entriesResult " + entriesResult.length);
```

is executed **immediately** after you start the async operation (before it completes).

the line in the callback function is executed later, after the async operation is complete.